# What is the best place to sleep health-wise inside an M1 Abrams tank?

Tags: military, nuclear-weapons, sleep, radioactivity, bio-weapons

There are several characters crossing an NBC-laden apocalyptic landscape in an [M1A1 Abrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1_Abrams) tank. For various reasons irrelevant to the scope of this question, they cannot leave to set up some kind of camp outside the tank; moreover, Abrams, and many [3rd-generation MBTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_main_battle_tanks_by_generation#Third_generation) are, IIRC, designed to operate while buttoned up - i.e. sealed against the outside.

What is the best place to sleep health-wise in an M1A1?

By health-wise, I mean "doesn't cause back injury", you wake up with the blood in all your extremities, no cramps, you didn't indent a bolt into your face, etc.

I recognize that there's really no good option here, given that it's a tank, and things like "padding" and "bedding" are dead weight and a flammability hazard, but just give me the least-worst option.

Comment: It cant be a very long journey because the MI simply doesn't have the room inside it to store significant amounts of food, water and fuel. Especially fuel, all tanks are fuel hogs & the Abrams is no exception - it only carries enough or 260 miles or so & there's no way of refueling it without exiting the vehicle. You could remove all the ammo from the storage bays to create storage space but that's about it. Even with their personal kit items doing that would let you squeeze enough food and water inside to last a while. But fuel would have to be stored externally. Thats a lot of jerry cans!

Comment: @Mon They "only" need to go from Valencia, Spain, to Madrid, Spain - about 220 and three-quarters miles - and they have a full tank (both in terms of fuel and in terms of the crew taking up the inside, ha-ha). Food and water are not really concerns. The things outside the tank are.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Why do they need to sleep?  If they're only going ~220 miles they should be able to get there in just a few hours.  Even assuming the terrain is terrible and they can only make 20mph, that's still just an 11 hour trip.

Comment: @Ryan_L They've been awake since about six in the morning that day fighting their way into a extradimensional abomination-infested international tank depot on the outskirts of Valencia, Spain, and, while Madrid is a safezone that they're trying to get to, the area around it is undergoing thermonuclear bombardment within the next twelve hours, and the next safezone is ~600 miles away so stopping is a non-option.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE They should make that trip in roughly 4 hours and 53 minutes of travel, in fact they have to, the Abrams averages 45mph on the road and if they go much slower than that they can't make the trip at all. They are pushing the road range of their vehicle (265 miles maximum on optimum fuel and good roads) close to the limit, if they have to go off road or idle in/drive over traffic for any great distance they will ***not*** get as far as Madrid. I'm not saying they don't need to sleep but given the stress of the situation they may not be able to without time to get bored on the road.

Comment: key-abrade: Referencing your response to my post above. NONE of those facts were stated in your original question. (Otherwise I wouldn't have bothered to respond in the first place.) If the tank is only 200 miles from its destination then what exactly is the problem in the first place? The crew can stay 'sealed up' for the duration of the journey and get by on water bottles and a couple chocolate bars during the journey - nothing outside the should effect them. And at 20 mph the driver won't need relief! So what's the problem in the first place?

Comment: @Mon I know what you're saying but they don't have the fuel to go that slow, the Abrams uses a jet engine that consumes fuel rapidly regardless of rate of travel  (not *quite* as fast at lower speeds but fast enough that slowing down makes a major dent in operational range), they have to go full pelt, by road, 45mph, or they are not going to get to Madrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I recall in the assigned seating is actually designed to be the least bad option for sleeping in most tanks that are built for extended duty. Contrary to the options of every tank driver ever born the designers do *try* to make the seating in tanks as comfortable as humanly possible given the other design considerations that must take precedence. If your tank is overloaded and no further seating is available I believe the answer is wherever you can find room to settle without having your elbow in someone else's eye because you can barely turn around in those things.